# NSIS - FindProc

Tags: nsis

Not sure why the below code would not work in NSIS.

I expect to show abort retry , ignore button with this and if the response is retry , reenter the loop. if abort then go to label abort. ELse continue.

```
lbl_InvertorRunningCheck:
    FindProcDLL::FindProc "Invertor.exe"     
    ${if} $R0 == 1
        MessageBox MB_TOPMOST|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE "Invertor process is running" IDRETRY lbl_InvertorRunningCheckIDABORT lbl_Abort ;
        lbl_Abort:
        Abort   
    ${EndIf}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your error is, but you are missing a space between lbl_InvertorRunningCheck and IDABORT.

If Ignore is selected, it is going to go to your Abort command because you did not specify what should happen if Ignore is pressed.

Try this:

```
lbl_InvertorRunningCheck:
FindProcDLL::FindProc "Invertor.exe"     
${if} $R0 == 1
    MessageBox MB_TOPMOST|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE "Invertor process is running" IDRETRY lbl_InvertorRunningCheck IDABORT lbl_Abort IDIGNORE lbl_Ignore
    lbl_Abort:
    Abort   
${EndIf}
lbl_Ignore:
```